# calling PostgreSQL function using EclipseLink

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, eclipselink

I am converting my project database from Oracle to PostgreSQL. I found many tutorials which depicts how to call function and process its data.

My question is there any way to or methods are available for eclipseLink to call the function and process the data using resultset etc.. rather than using **CallableStatement**.

Currently i am using **StoredProcedureCall** to call the procedure.

Comment: You don't need a `CallableStatement`, just use `select function_name()` for scalar functions or `select * from function_name()` for functions returning tables

Comment: in my case i have to pass parameters while calling the function and i don't know how to set the output type in eclipseLink

Comment: Use a regular `PreparedStatement` with placeholders: `select function_Name(?,?)`, then run `executeQuery()`